# Where can I find settings-variable-reference visual studio code documentation ? (e.g : $fileName, $fileNameWithoutExt)

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I'm using the **Code Runner** extension in vs code,

I want to change the output directory of compiled-cpp (.exe) files but I don't know what variable-name I will type in

- my "settings.json" file :

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    
        "javascript": "node",
        "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt", // <- this
```

Is anyone know where the variable-name documentation for this case ? anyway sorry for my bad english

I've tried to implement from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference like this :

```
"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $file -o $workspaceFolder\\C++\\bin\\$fileNameWithoutExt && $workspaceFolder\\C++\\bin\\$fileNameWithoutExt",
```

and I got :
[Unexpected token '\C++\bin\stringComparison' in expression or statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJOvv.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[formulahendry/vscode-code-runner: Code Runner for Visual Studio Code (github.com)](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner)

> **Supported customized parameters**
>
> - $workspaceRoot: The path of the folder opened in VS Code
> - $dir: The directory of the code file being run
> - $dirWithoutTrailingSlash: The directory of the code file being run without a trailing slash
> - $fullFileName: The full name of the code file being run
> - $fileName: The base name of the code file being run, that is the file without the directory
> - $fileNameWithoutExt: The base name of the code file being run without its extension
> - $driveLetter: The drive letter of the code file being run (Windows only)
> - $pythonPath: The path of Python interpreter (set by `Python: Select Interpreter` command)
>
> **Please take care of the back slash and the space in file path of the executor**
>
> - Back slash: please use `\\`
> - If there ares spaces in file path, please use `\"` to surround your file path

Answer (score 1):

Open `Visual Studio Code` -> `Setting` -> `Upper right corner` -> `Press open setting.json` and then edit the code runner executorMap `"cpp"` with this command.

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++17 \"$fileName\" -o \"$fileNameWithoutExt.o\" && $dir\"$fileNameWithoutExt.o\"",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your path is - /home/your-username/your-project/folder/file.cpp Now you make a "build" directory in which you can output your compiled files with path - /home/your-username/your-project/folder/build

So you change your setting.json to this

OLD:
"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",

NEW:
"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $dir/build/$fileNameWithoutExt && $dir/build/$fileNameWithoutExt",